# Can I record video without using junit?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-junit, testcontainers

Good day!
Can I record video without using junit? I use cucumber

```
public static target BrowserWebDriverContainer <?> container = new BrowserWebDriverContainer <> () .withCapabilities (en.sbtqa.tag.pagefactory.drivers.Capabilities.getFirefoxOptions ())
.withRecordingMode (VncRecordingMode.RECORD_ALL, new file ("target"), VncRecordingFormat.MP4) .withStartupTimeout (Duration.ofMinutes (2)). withNetwork (Network.newNetwork ());
container.start();
```

use  cucumber.api.java.Before

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use JUnit integration with Testcontainers.

Testcontainers allows you to control lifecycle of the containers manually if you want: https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/

You need to create the container:

```
public static BrowserWebDriverContainer <?> container = new BrowserWebDriverContainer<>()
  .withCapabilities (en.sbtqa.tag.pagefactory.drivers.Capabilities.getFirefoxOptions())
  .withRecordingMode (VncRecordingMode.RECORD_ALL, new File("target"), VncRecordingFormat.MP4)
  .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
  .withNetwork(Network.newNetwork());
```

Then start it:

```
container.start();
```

You can also manually stop the container using `container.stop()`,
But you don't have to stop the container yourself, by default it'll be stopped after the JVM process finishes.